# Files not appearing on github

Tags: github, repository, git-bash, git-push

I am new to web development and have just created my first project. I created a new repository on github and then did the following on git bash:

1. Moved to the working directory for my project
2. Initialized the git repository using git init
3. Added my files using git add .
4. Committed the files using git commit -m 'my message'
5. Added the github URL under code. on github by using git remote add origin 'my_url_name'
6. Pushed the code to github using git push -u origin master (also entered my passphrase correctly as I am using SSH)
7. Git Bash confirmed the upload and then nothing appeared on my repository on github
8. Note. I did get a message at the top of the repository saying "master had recent pushes x minutes ago: with a button that says "Compare & pull request" though the page just shows a message "There isn't anything to compare."

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are selecting the correct branch on github. At the top of the repository, on the same line as "Go to file" "Add file" and "Code" on the far left is a button to select the branch. Make sure the branch is the same as the branch used as origin when the push was declared on Git Bash.

Answer (score 1):

The branch selected in your **git** is **master**. But in GitHub is **main**. To display your codes in GitHub, you need to change the Git branch to main.
First delete previous repository in Github and create a new , then act according to the following codes in the git :

```
git branch main 
git checkout main
git merge master
git branch -M main
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/masoud8911/example.git
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your local branch name is `main` not master. You can check this locally with:

```
git branch.
```

try instead:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Thanks. I entered git branch and it came back saying * master.
When I used git push -u origin main it came back saying 
"error: src refspec main does not match any"
"error: failed to push some refs to 'my_url.git"